# Disable offsetting content on hover selector

Tags: css

When I'm hovering content inside div I'm getting offsets toward right side, I know that's because I'm adding left border, but how can I avoid this?

```
ul li:hover {
  border-left: 4px solid #FF2F5A;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eeeek/j8xaru7m/

Comment: Add a transparent border of the same width on the non-hover state ...

Comment: Yeah, ``not()`` is better idea than no state.

Comment: @CBroe, your ellipsis describes my question, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by that, how to target the items when they are not in a hovered stated? Well `ul li { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While one can set a transparent border for the non-hovered state, that might sometimes given unwanted alignment.

Here is a solution using a pseudo element that overcomes that. The `position: relative;` on the `ul li` is necessary for the absolute positioned pseudo to position itself properly.

```css
ul li {
  position: relative;                /*  added property  */
  margin-left: -26px;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 491px;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
}

ul li > span {
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

ul li:hover::before {                 /*  updated rule  */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0;
  width: 4px; background: #FF2F5A;
}

.items {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -17.7px;
}

.block-with-items-style {
  margin-left: 50px;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #f2f2f2;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #adadad;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-with-items-style">
  <div class="items">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="record in records">
        <span>1</span>
        <span class="badge badge-style">2</span>
        <button class="delete" ng-click="Delete($index)">3</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Bonus: This way one can easily add an animation as well

```css
ul li {
  position: relative;                /*  added property  */
  margin-left: -26px;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 491px;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
}

ul li > span {
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

ul li::before {                      /*  added rule  */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 0; bottom: 50%;
  width: 4px; background: #FF2F5A;
  transition: top .5s, bottom .5s;
}
ul li:hover::before {                /*  updated rule  */
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
}

.items {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -17.7px;
}

.block-with-items-style {
  margin-left: 50px;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #f2f2f2;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #adadad;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-with-items-style">
  <div class="items">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="record in records">
        <span>1</span>
        <span class="badge badge-style">2</span>
        <button class="delete" ng-click="Delete($index)">3</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create invisible (100% alpha) border with previous css directive. As long `hover` is active – it will overwrite that transparent border with red. Here's the code:

```css
ul li {
  margin-left: -26px;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 491px;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
}

ul li > span {
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

/* Sylogista's upgrade begin */

ul li:not(:hover)
{
  border-left: 4px solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
}

/* Sylogista's upgrade end */

ul li:hover {
  border-left: 4px solid #FF2F5A;
}

.items {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -17.7px;
}

.block-with-items-style {
  margin-left: 50px;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #f2f2f2;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #adadad;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-with-items-style">
  <div class="items">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="record in records">
        <span>1</span>
        <span class="badge badge-style">2</span>
        <button class="delete" ng-click="Delete($index)">3</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

`:not(:hover)` is optional. Code will work good without it, but in my opinion – using that can be good practice. When? That's not place for debate, but let me give one short example in the margin of that answer: when you're creating huge css using many of states in that way and relations between elements – it just looks clearer.
In that case it's clearer maybe without it, but I'll not change that. Even just because of that not so many people use `:not` or even remember about that.

Comment: _"Writing state :not(:hover) isn't nesesery, but it's good idea to use it. Code will work even without it, but sometimes it's really good idea to use :not() state. That's sometimes just good practice."_ - you're stating three times what a good idea this (allegedly) was, but you have not presented a single argument for it.

Comment: @CBroe Right... well – that's how it looks like when you're doing too many things at the same time. Thanks.